# Transaction not found in Blockchain

Tags: bitcoind

Trying to send a transaction via `bitcoin-cli`. It seems to be working on my end but if I look up the transaction ID `76f2b87d7fbd18a217626761cdea215b66d523a3471e446c4fb0147645647866` on any block explorers, it tells me not found.

I've tried to push it using https://blockchain.info/pushtx, but again I get a not found error. Doing the same on blockr.io gives me `Did you sign your transaction? Is this double spend? Have you already sent this transaction?`

I'm not sure how to debug this or fix it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Hex representation:

> 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

Comment: What software package and version created this transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending this transaction through my own Bitcoin Core 0.13.99 node:

```
error message:
64: too-long-mempool-chain
```

This means you're building a long chain of unconfirmed transactions that depend on each other. Wait until the first few of those have confirmed before creating more.

Comment: Will it automatically enter the chain once that happens or will I need to rebroadcast it? How can I get the transaction ids it's depending on?

Comment: Also, which command do you use to send that? If I do the same, will it be the same as using blockchain.info's pushtx tool?

Comment: It depends, if it's a transaction relevant to your wallet, and your node is running, it will automatically rebroadcast as needed (the upcoming 0.14 release of Bitcoin Core improves upon this). If not, you'll need to manually rebroadcast with `sendrawtransaction` (which is what I used to broadcast). Don't rely on blockchain.info, it's perpetually outdated.

Comment: bookmark this link for submitting transactions: https://www.smartbit.com.au/txs/pushtx

Comment: @Rob Anyone can submit the transaction now that you've made it public. It's almost certain that someone will.

Comment: Is that problematic somehow?