# Resolve BTC long mem pool (many unconfirmed tx)

Tags: bitcoin-core, mempool

I've started with Bitcoin exchange service, by creating rawtransaction and broadcast it. The problem which I must face to face is too long mempool chain (over 25 unconfirmed transaction). 

Example: 
[64: too-long-mempool-chain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59178/64-too-long-mempool-chain)

Using `limitancestorcount` and `limitdescendantcount` just resolve on local node, these late txs (transaction after first 25) must wait for a long period time to re-broadcast like this: 
[Transaction not found in Blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51255/transaction-not-found-in-blockchain/51256#51256)

Here is my testnet address has many unconfirmed txs and still pending hold, if I search on another explorer, I can't see 45 unconfirmed txs, same to `getrawtransaction` on node, response is `No such mempool or blockchain transaction`:

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/mxHqrQBWuCndNaubTYUbcEVzeNPsT34TP6/

So, how can I avoid this issue, I just think few ways such as: Divide main address to few sub addresses which divides main UTXO to few UTXOs, create many-to-many transaction (currently is 1-2, 1 target and 1 changeAddress back), using high confirmation UTXO first,... Which options can bring better result and performance for a long time scaling up? Any advice is really appreciate. And last question, is there anyway to mark 1 UTXO that is used for 25 times (example I use UTXO X first, then it's returned Y, use Y is returned Z, total using X = 2, I don't have any related information to calculate it because node returns UTXO contains only txId).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, make many sub UTXOs will resolve that well.